# Which hydrocolloids before adding cheese culture?

Tags: lactofermentation

My mesophilic starter will start to die at 40c.
I would like to thicken my nutcheese base and stir while cooling to under 40c, preferably 30c, before mixing in starter and allowing to set.

What choices do I have beyond xanthan and guar for a firm gel that won't 'break' at 30 - 40c?

Tapioca starch will allow stirring in that range but a kappa carrageenan-like gel would be ideal.